# Python Beautiful Soup loop

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a loop to go through the links multiple times and it only runs once and seems to disgard all other code besides the Beautiful Soup code

```
import requests
import bs4

x = 0

while  x < 3:
    print(x)
    res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    i = soup.select('.firstHeading')
    print(i.text)
    x += 1
else:
    print('Done')
    
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write('soup')
f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate which print doesn't run for you?

Comment: You probably have that err:
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

For that line:
print(i.text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have err for `print(i.text)`,

`i` is a `List` in your case,

Probably need `print(i[0].text)`:

```
import requests
import bs4

x = 0

while x < 3:
    print(x)
    res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    i = soup.select('.firstHeading')
    print(i[0].text)
    x += 1
else:
    print('Done')

f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write('soup')
f.close()
```

And you will have OUTPUT:

```
0
Liu Jianfu
1
Rees Edgar Tulloss
2
List of Ed episodes
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

soup.select('.firstHeading') will give you a list. So in order to get text from firstHeading, you have to iterate through it, like:

```
i = soup.select('.firstHeading')
    print(i)
    for j in i:
        print(j.text)
    x += 1
```

or you can use soup.find() like this:

```
 i = soup.find(class_='firstHeading')
 print(i.text)
 x += 1
```